# How are imports chosen for consoleProject?

Tags: sbt

I'm using sbt 0.13.5-SNAPSHOT built from the sources.

When I ran `consoleProject` command, I could see the following imports:

```
> consoleProject
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info]
import sbt._
import Keys._
import currentState._
import extracted._
import cpHelpers._
```

Why are these imports important and selected for the command? I can explain the first two imports, but vaguely recognise the others.